# How to set datatable header column fields to a Gridview HeaderTemplate Label control Text

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, .net-3.5

I want to set datatable header column fields to a Label controls Text property of a  Gridview HeaderTemplate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but if you want to bind from a datasource to Labels within a TemplateField's HeaderTemplate and ItemTemplate, you can do this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="YourField">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("header_database_field") %>'/>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("content_database_field") %>'/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Where `header_database_field` and `content_database_field` are the fields from your database that you wish to bind.

If you want to assign a DataTable's column name(s) to one of the TemplateField's Labels, you could do something like this programmatically during the RowDataBound event, though I'm not sure why you'd want to:

```
DataTable datatable = new DataTable(); // your dt

protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        ((Label)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[1]).Text = datatable.Columns[0].ColumnName;
    }
}
```

Reaplce `datatable` with your DataTable, and modify the indexes to reference your Cell/Label(s)/ColumnNames.